# Make calendar dynamically in 3.7

Tags: javascript, joomla-3.7, calendar

I recently found out that the datepicker and calendar changed a lot from 3.6 to 3.7 and as a result I'm having a problem with my custom backend component. Originally this is the code I was using to initialize my datepickers:

```
$("input[name^='jform[date]']").each(function(index){
    Calendar.setup({
        inputField: $(this).attr('id'),
        ifFormat: '%m/%d/%Y',
        button: $(this).attr('id') + '_img',
        align: 'Tl',
        singleClick: true,
        firstDay: 0
    });
});
```

I was informed that I now have to use `JoomlaCalendar.init()` instead of `Calendar.setup`.

My question is if the parameters are set the same way or if they're even the same. I looked around but I can't find much about this update.

Is there a core file that I can use as an example or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around, I finally found the answer or at least got it to work. Not sure if there is a better way.

First off, originally I was initializing from the input field. We now have to do it from the parent of the parent node, so the input field must be embedded inside two elements. Secondly, I was originally initializing with the `id` of the field, we now have to do it with the `element` itself; I switched from jquery to vanilla javascript.

As far as the parameters, I couldn't find any samples where the parameters were being set the old way and I couldn't get it to work by setting them that way either. So I passed the parameters as `data` attribute values assigned to the button that triggers the datepicker. I just copied the parameters and values from one of the jform input fields.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="field-calendar">                      
    <div class="input-append">                          
        <input id="jform_date1" name="jform[date][]" title="" type="text"
               aria-invalid="false" class="input-medium hasTooltip" maxlength="45"
               value="" data-original-title="" data-alt-value="0000-00-00 00:00:00">
        <button class="btn" id="jform_date1_img" type="button" data-inputfield="jform_date1"
                data-dayformat="%m/%d/%Y" data-button="jform_date_btn" data-firstday="0"
                data-weekend="0,6" data-today-btn="1" data-week-numbers="1" data-show-time="0"
                data-show-others="1" data-time-24="24" data-only-months-nav="0">
            <span class="icon-calendar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And  here is my javascript:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("#webinarSeries .field-calendar");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    JoomlaCalendar.init(elements[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on chavab_1's answer, this answer uses Joomla's interface to create the html and adds a date dynamically when a button is clicked. I left the id field blank as it doesn't seem to be required for the calendar to work.

```
jQuery('#add_date').click(function()
{

cal_html = <?php echo json_encode(JHTML::calendar(date("m-d-Y"),'custcal[]', '', '%m-%d-%Y',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',))); ?>;

jQuery('#datelist').append(cal_html);

JoomlaCalendar.init((jQuery('#datelist .field-calendar').last())[0]); 

});
```

Comment: Welcome to JSE. If you make a mistake while posting an answer, please [edit] it to make the desired changes instead of deleting and posting a new answer.

Comment: Thanx for this update. Do you know if this will still work on Joomla 4? I haven't had to use the calendar, or datepicker, this way on any of my Joomla 4 sites. I was just wondering for future reference.

Comment: I tried to edit, but I'm not used to the editor yet and I kept messing up the formatting.  This edit uses json_encode instead of str_replace.  I do not know if it will work on Joomla 4.  I see a number of people having issues with J4 and many extensions haven't been updated yet, so I am waiting for it to stabilize more before updating the half dozen sites I'm responsible for.